# Symmetry of the output activation function vs symmetry of the output

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, backpropagation

Imagine you have a reinforcement learning problem in which your continuous action space is $\mathcal{A} = [-0.01, 1.5]$  which is associated with a deterministic policy. As you notice the upper and lower values are **not symmetric** with respect to zero.

Let us choose **tanh** as the output activation function; in addition a (keras) network structure could be:

```
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(4))
out = layers.Dense(20, activation="swish")(inputs) 
out = layers.Dense(30, activation="swish")(out) 
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="tanh", kernel_initializer = my_init)(out)
outputs = outputs*1.5
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

After that the output model is clipped between the requested action space since it provides values between $[-1.5,1.5]$

My question is: is the tanh symmetry around zero a bad match with a non-symmetric output around zero?

Comment: Why not simply apply an affine transformation to map [-1,1] to [-0.01,1.5] if you want to use the tanh activation?

Comment: Are you supposing to use a tanh, whose amplitude is 0.8, clipping it into [-0.7,+0.7] ?

Comment: The output of tanh is in [-1,1]. What I propose is to scale it with (1.5-(-0.01))/2=1.51/2 and then add (1.5+(-0.01))/2=1.49/2. That way, the final output will be in [-0.01,1.5], but you don't need to clip the outputs of the tanh.